# How can I connect a silicon hose with 2mm inner diameter to a smaller 1,9mm port

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pressure, sensors, pneumatic

The biggest diameter of my pressure sensor input port has a size of 1.93 mm. The silicon hose which I want to connect with the sensor's port has an inner diameter size of 2.0 mm.

My honeywell pressure sensor: [image: Honeywell pressure sensor]

My silicon hose: [image]

As you can imagine - it does not fit. The port is to small or the inner diameter of the silicon hose to large.

What is the best way to bring both together? Are there adapters availabe? What is the name therefore? What is a good way in engineering to fix such an issue?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: can you clamp/tie something around the hose to press it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fittings on your pressure sensor look like barb fittings. If that's the case, a 1.6mm ID silicone tubing will easily stretch over a 1.93mm barb fitting. 1.6mm (or 1/16") tubing is a fairly common size and you should be able to get it from standard laboratory suppliers.

You'll then need an adapter to go from your 2mm ID to 1.6mm ID silicone tubing. Again, 2.4mm (3/32") is a fairly common size and a 2mm ID silicone tubing will easily stretch over a 2.4mm barb fitting. So something like AD-6005 from [Nordson Medical](http://www.nordsonmedical.com/) or equivalent should do it:

[image]